# Upgrading laptop hard drive to ssd

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, windows-10

I'm upgrading my old [Asus Q200e](http://www.asus.com/supportonly/Q200E/HelpDesk_Manual/) laptop's hard drive to a PNY SSD `http://www.pny.com/ssd-cs2111?sku=SSD7CS2111-240-RB` , following this [tutorial](http://blog.laptopmag.com/ssd-upgrade-tutorial). (As an aside, I recently upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 due to a slight slowdown in boot times.) Aside from using different products than the ones listed in the tutorial, I've followed every step to the letter.

However, when I swapped out the HDD with the SSD, the computer does not recognize the new SSD as the boot drive. Instead, upon turning on the machine, the system goes into a strange BIOS-esque utility called "Aptio Setup Utility" that doesn't list the SSD at all. It does, however, list the boot manager from the old HDD I have plugged into a hard drive USB enclosure. I've tried looking up the answer online to no avail.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Windows again? To install Windows again, you should put in the DVD, start the laptop, then immediately start pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter the boot menu and boot to your DVD drive to begin the installation. You can then install Windows on your SSD.

Judging by your question, it sounds like you didn't install Windows again. If you have installed Windows, have you gone into the BIOS and checked/edited your boot order, and verify that it sees your SSD?

Comment: I used a cloning tool to copy everything from the HDD to the SSD. Shouldn't that negate the need for a Windows reinstallation? Honest question, I really don't know.

Comment: @CharlieGao yeah I think that should work as long as everything was done right, and all the information from the HDD was able to fit onto the SSD. I haven't used cloning software much, and it's been a few years since I have. It sounds like you still have the old HDD attached through a USB connection. Have you tried removing that, then tried booting up the system?

Comment: I have, attempting to boot without the old HDD shows that the computer does not recognize the new SSD as a drive

Comment: @CharlieGao go into your BIOS and see if the SSD is listed as an available boot device. If possible take a picture of it with a camera or something and give a link to where you uploaded it.

Comment: The SSD is not listed at all. I'll need to put the SSD back in to get a picture, but I'm working on it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MQSoZMZ.jpg there's not a real BIOS, instead it's this underpowered BIOS-like tool called Aptio

Comment: @CharlieGao enable CSM

Comment: The system just reboots with no change, couldn't get a picture

Comment: @CharlieGao pop in the installation DVD if you have it and go through the installation steps to the point where it shows the available drives that you can install on, see if the SSD is listed, then abort the install. I think the boot sector on the SSD is either broken or missing. Since you still have the original HDD with all of the data, you could always copy it back onto the SSD after an install.

Comment: I don't have an installation disk, I had upgraded to windows 10 from a preinstalled copy of windows

Comment: @Charlie Gao, You can download a copy of windows 10 & do a clean install with it.